# Getdate() in sql-server 2019 giving wrong date

Tags: datetime, getdate, sql-server-2019

I am simply running the below command :

```
select getdate()
```

and I am getting below same result for last 30 min:

```
2020-07-21 15:45:14
```

Which is incorrect. Also it's not changing with every second.

Not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: What does the following return you

SELECT CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME())
    ,CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
    ,CONVERT (time, SYSUTCDATETIME())
    ,CONVERT (time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ,CONVERT (time, GETDATE())
    ,CONVERT (time, GETUTCDATE());

Comment: first 2 are giving the right time.

Comment: 18:47:29 18:47:29 13:17:29 15:45:14 15:45:14 10:14:20

Comment: the answer you accepted is wrong. Probably you are getting the same issue as the people here https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/654

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are probably querying a replicate, the getdate() returns the latest database system timestamp, not the system time of the local machine.

```
SELECT CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME())
    ,CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
    ,CONVERT (time, SYSUTCDATETIME())
    ,CONVERT (time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ,CONVERT (time, GETDATE())
    ,CONVERT (time, GETUTCDATE());
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

If you need to know the local computer time, then use SYSDATETIME instead

Comment: are you saying that getdate() does not return current date time ?

Comment: @Manish it returns the current time as the database knows it, but as it is a replica, that’s the time it last replicated the data from primary node.

Comment: now if i am running "select getdate()" it's giving correct date time. Strange.

Comment: @Manish so the replica is in-sync with the primary.

Comment: I am not much clear about replica and primary concept of sql-server So let me tell you my requirement. I have to soft delete the record so whenever there is a delete request I am updating the expiry_dt from NULL to getdate(). So should i depend on getdate() to fetch current datetime when delete request was processed.

Comment: @Manish use sysdatetime() instead.

Comment: @MarcelDumont I always thought getdate value is generaged from system whenever it is executed. Can you give any reference that GetDate values can be stale

Comment: The documentation you yourself link states "This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running."